# Android - Clicking on a Button errors immediately without entering the onClick activity

Tags: android, button, invocationtargetexception

I have the following code with SupervisorActivity.java and activity_supervisor.xml files. The form displays as expected, however when I click on the button I get the following error. I am fairly new and tried to find the issue by stepping through the code though I'm unable to step through as clicking on the button doesn't even go to the SaveSupervisor code.

DBHandler.java

```
package com.smith.john.learnerlog;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by d402966 on 24/03/2016.
 */
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Static Variables
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LearnerLog";
    private static final String TABLE_SUPERVISOR = "supervisors";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String KEY_LICENCE_NO = "licence_no";
    private static final String KEY_CREATE_DATE = "create_date";


    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    /*Override this function to create a new table*/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_SUPERVISOR_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SUPERVISOR + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LICENCE_NO + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATE_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SUPERVISOR_TABLE);
    }

    /*Override this function to upgrade your table design / structure*/
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Drop the old table if exists
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SUPERVISOR);
    // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    /*addSupervisor() will add a new Supervisor to database*/
public long addSupervisor(Supervisor supervisor) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, supervisor.getName());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, supervisor.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, supervisor.getPhone());
        values.put(KEY_LICENCE_NO, supervisor.getLicenceNo());
        values.put(KEY_CREATE_DATE, supervisor.getCreateDate());

    return db.insert(TABLE_SUPERVISOR, null, values); //Insert query to store the record in the database
    }


    /*getSupervisor() will return he supervisor's object if id matches*/
public Supervisor getSupervisor(int supervisor_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SUPERVISOR, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PHONE, KEY_LICENCE_NO, KEY_CREATE_DATE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(supervisor_id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Supervisor supervisor = new Supervisor(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
        return supervisor;
    }

    /*getAllSupervisors() will return the list of all supervisors*/
    public ArrayList<Supervisor> getAllSupervisors() {
        ArrayList<Supervisor> supervisorsList = new ArrayList<Supervisor>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SUPERVISOR;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String cursor_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
                String cursor_email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL));
                String cursor_phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE));
                String cursor_licence_no = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LICENCE_NO));
                String cursor_create_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATE_DATE));
            Supervisor supervisor = new Supervisor(cursor_name, cursor_email, cursor_phone, cursor_licence_no, cursor_create_date);
                supervisorsList.add(supervisor);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return supervisorsList;
    }
    /*getSupervisorsCount() will give the total number of records in the table*/
    public int getSupervisorsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SUPERVISOR;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    /*updateSupervisor() will be used to update the existing supervisor record*/
    public int updateSupervisor(Supervisor supervisor) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, supervisor.getName());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, supervisor.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, supervisor.getPhone());
        values.put(KEY_LICENCE_NO, supervisor.getLicenceNo());
        values.put(KEY_CREATE_DATE, supervisor.getCreateDate());
        // updating record
        return db.update(TABLE_SUPERVISOR, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", // update query to make changes to the existing record
                new String[]{String.valueOf(supervisor.getId())});
    }

    /*deleteContact() to delete the record from the table*/
    public void deleteContact(Supervisor supervisor) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_SUPERVISOR, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(supervisor.getId())});
    db.close();
}
    public void deleteAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete FROM " + TABLE_SUPERVISOR);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
03-30 23:47:57.079 2140-2140/com.smith.john.learnerlog E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.smith.john.learnerlog, PID: 2140
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                                                                             at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                                                                             at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                             at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                             at com.smith.john.learnerlog.DBHandler.getSupervisor(DBHandler.java:79)
                                                                             at com.smith.john.learnerlog.SupervisorActivity.SaveSupervisor(SupervisorActivity.java:174)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-30 23:48:01.647 2140-2146/com.smith.john.learnerlog W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.223ms
```

SupervisorActivity.java

```
package com.smith.john.learnerlog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by d402966 on 24/03/2016.
 */
public class SupervisorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
    public DBHandler mydb;
    Supervisor supervisor;
    Cursor rs;
    TextView name;
    TextView email;
    TextView phone;
    TextView licence_no;
    int id_To_Update = 0;
    int id_value;
    String name_value;
    String email_value;
    String licence_no_value;
    String phone_value;
    String create_date_value;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private SupervisorsAdapter adapter;
    private DBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_supervisor);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        licence_no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextLicenceNo);

        mydb = new DBHandler(this);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");

            if (Value > 0) {
                //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
                supervisor = mydb.getSupervisor(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;
                rs.moveToFirst();

                name_value = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(supervisor.getName()));
                email_value = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(supervisor.getEmail()));
                phone_value = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(supervisor.getPhone()));
                licence_no_value = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(supervisor.getLicenceNo()));


                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                name.setText((CharSequence) name_value);
                name.setFocusable(true);
                name.setClickable(true);
                email.setText((CharSequence) email_value);
                email.setFocusable(true);
                email.setClickable(true);
                phone.setText((CharSequence) phone_value);
                phone.setFocusable(true);
                phone.setClickable(true);
                licence_no.setText((CharSequence) licence_no_value);
                licence_no.setFocusable(true);
                licence_no.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_supervisor, menu);
            } else {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Edit_Supervisor:
                name.setEnabled(true);
                name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                name.setClickable(true);
                email.setEnabled(true);
                email.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                email.setClickable(true);
                phone.setEnabled(true);
                phone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                phone.setClickable(true);
                licence_no.setEnabled(true);
                licence_no.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                licence_no.setClickable(true);

                return true;
            case R.id.Delete_Supervisor:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
/*                builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteSupervisor)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                mydb.deleteSupervisor(id_To_Update);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog d = builder.create();
                d.setTitle("Are you sure");
                d.show();

*/                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

   }

    public void SaveSupervisor(View view) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
        SupervisorsAdapter adapter;
        DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);
        Supervisor supervisor;


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if (extras != null) {
            supervisor = mydb.getSupervisor(Value);
            create_date_value = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(supervisor.getCreateDate()));
            if (create_date_value.matches("")) {
                create_date_value = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
            }
            if (Value > 0) {
                if (mydb.updateSupervisor(supervisor) == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                supervisor.setName(name.getText().toString());
                supervisor.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                supervisor.setPhone(phone.getText().toString());
                supervisor.setLicenceNo(licence_no.getText().toString());
            supervisor.setCreateDate(create_date_value.toString());
                if (mydb.addSupervisor(supervisor) == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_supervisor.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.aksu.ozgur.learnerlog.SupervisorActivity" >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/name" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/Email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Name">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/Phone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Email">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/phone"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/LicenceNo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Phone">

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextLicenceNo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/licence_no"
                    android:inputType="time"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/SaveSupervisorButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
                android:onClick="SaveSupervisor"
                android:text="@string/save_supervisor"
                android:layout_below="@+id/LicenceNo"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your `getSupervisor()` method in your `DBHandler` class please? The error log suggests you're attempting to pull data from a `Cursor` which is empty.

Comment: I've updated the submission with the DBHandler.java in full.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace points to a `CursorIndexOutOfBounds` exception, which in this case means the `Cursor` inside your `getSupervisor()` method is empty. You can test for this by making the following adjustment to your method:

```
/*getSupervisor() will return he supervisor's object if id matches*/
public Supervisor getSupervisor(int supervisor_id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SUPERVISOR, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PHONE, KEY_LICENCE_NO, KEY_CREATE_DATE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(supervisor_id)}, null, null, null, null);
        //if (cursor != null) <--Replace this. The query() method never returns a null Cursor

        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //Cursor is empty...
            throw new CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException("Cursor should not be empty");
        }

        Supervisor supervisor = new Supervisor(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
        return supervisor;
    }
```

If you want to have it so that the `supervisor_id` provided not having an entry in your database is valid, then you can replace the `throw new CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException()` with a blank `Supervisor`:

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    return new Supervisor("","","","","");
}
```

Otherwise, the problem either lies in the `supverisor_id` you're passing to the method or in your `query()`

Comment: That's resolved the Cursor Index out of Bounds issue and I am now able to stop the processing and step through the code. There are further issues such as getColumnIndex being called on an entry where the column value is not defined. I'll work through those and post back if I continue to have issues.

Appreciate your help!!!